# How to keep old values of other fields after selectOneMenu change

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, selectonemenu

I have a p:selectOneMenu, when the value change I show/hide other fields, but other fields are reset.

```
<h:panelGrid columns="1" >
    <p:outputLabel value="Usuario" />
    <p:inputText value="#{controladorGestionUsuario.usuario.usuario}"
                 size="30" 
                 placeholder="Usuario"
                 required="true"
                 requiredMessage="Ingrese el usuario"/>
</h:panelGrid>
<h:panelGrid columns="1" >
    <p:outputLabel value="Rol" />
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{controladorGestionUsuario.nombreRol}"
                     style="width: 200px" 
                     required="true"
                     requiredMessage="Seleccione un rol" >
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione un rol" itemValue="#{null}" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{controladorGestionUsuario.roles}" 
                       var="rol"
                       itemLabel="#{rol.nombre}" itemValue="#{rol.nombre}" />
        <p:ajax update="sedes instituciones :form:pnlContenedor" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
</h:panelGrid>
<h:panelGrid columns="1" 
             id="instituciones" 
             rendered="#{controladorGestionUsuario.nombreRol != null and controladorGestionUsuario.nombreRol != controladorGestionUsuario.nombreRolAdminSistema}">
    <p:outputLabel value="Institución" />
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{controladorGestionUsuario.idInstitucion}"
                     style="width: 200px" 
                     required="true"
                     requiredMessage="Seleccione una institución" >
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione una institución" itemValue="#{null}" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{controladorGestionUsuario.instituciones}" 
                       var="institucion"
                       itemLabel="#{institucion.nombre}" 
                       itemValue="#{institucion.id}" />
        <p:ajax update="sedes :form:pnlContenedor"
                listener="#{controladorGestionUsuario.manejarCambioInstitucion}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
</h:panelGrid>
<h:panelGrid columns="1" 
             id="sedes" 
             rendered="#{controladorGestionUsuario.nombreRol != null and controladorGestionUsuario.nombreRol != controladorGestionUsuario.nombreRolAdminSistema}">
    <p:outputLabel value="Sede" />
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{controladorGestionUsuario.idSede}"
                     style="width: 200px" 
                     required="true"
                     requiredMessage="Seleccione una sede" >
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione una sede" itemValue="#{null}" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{controladorGestionUsuario.sedes}" 
                       var="sede"
                       itemLabel="#{sede.nombre}" 
                       itemValue="#{sede.id}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
</h:panelGrid>
```

When I selected a value of "Rol" show/hide the panel "instituciones" and "sedes", but the input "Usuario" is reseted.

How do I keep the value of field "Usuario"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How I can change the value of "selectOneMenu" without restart the "inputText"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23276928/how-i-can-change-the-value-of-selectonemenu-without-restart-the-inputtext)

Comment: Please do not re-ask the same question when you want to improve it. Just edit the original question, it'll be bumped up anyway.