# How I can change the value of "selectOneMenu" without restart the "inputText"?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

I have the next code:

```
<h:form id="form" >
    <h:panelGrid >
        <p:inputText placeholder="Name" value="#{controladorGestionGrados.otherValue}" />
        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{controladorGestionGrados.value}" >
            <f:selectItem itemValue="A" itemLabel="A" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="B" itemLabel="B" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="C" itemLabel="C" />
            <p:ajax update=":form"  />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
        <p:outputLabel id="someText"
                       value="Some text" 
                       rendered="#{controladorGestionGrados.value eq 'C'}" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

First: I write anything in the inputText.
Second: I select option C.

After, the outputLabel "Some text" is displayed, but the inputText is reseted.

How I can change the value of "selectOneMenu" without restart the "inputText"?

I've tried:

```
<p:ajax update="someText"  />
```

But effectively the inputText don't reset, but outLabel don't show.

Comment: You could bind the input text to a string in your backing bean, and then autosubmit on blur.

Comment: This a dummy example, really my code is more complex but I have the same problem. The inputext is bind from backing bean. How to do autosubmit on blur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your `<p:outputLabel>`

```
<p:outputLabel id="someText" value="Some text" rendered="#{controladorGestionGrados.value eq 'C'}" />
```

with a holder `<p:outputPanel>`

Like this :

```
<p:outputPanel id="someTextPanel">
<p:outputLabel id="someTextLabel" value="Some text" rendered="#{controladorGestionGrados.value eq 'C'}" />
</p:outputPanel>
```

And update the holder component (`<p:outputPanel>`) with

```
<p:ajax update="someTextPanel" />
```

So entire code should be something like this :

```
<h:form id="form" >
    <h:panelGrid >
        <p:inputText placeholder="Name" value="#{controladorGestionGrados.otherValue}" />
        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{controladorGestionGrados.value}" >
            <f:selectItem itemValue="A" itemLabel="A" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="B" itemLabel="B" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="C" itemLabel="C" />            
            <p:ajax update="someTextPanel" />
          </p:selectOneMenu>
       <p:outputPanel id="someTextPanel">
    <p:outputLabel id="someTextLabel" value="Some text" rendered="#{controladorGestionGrados.value eq 'C'}" />
    </p:outputPanel>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Fantastic! But did you understand why it is working ? It's in fact all about the presence in the DOM of the element to be dynamically rendered upon ajax update events. An element can't be updated if it is not there..

Comment: Yes Sir, I understand, in summary: if not present at the beginning, after can not manipulated.